# Understanding haskell code

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell. Can someone explain how I can interpret this line of code in haskell :

```
filter (\(_, (varible1, _)) -> variable1 `notElem` [something1, something2])
```

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?

Comment: Actually I cannot understand `filter (\(_, (varible1, _))` and also the flow in the code

Comment: I think you have to take a closer look at the brackets. `(\(_, (varible1, _)) -> variable1 \`notElem\` [something1, something2])` is a single lambda expression.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a good place to learn the bare-bones basics of a new programming language. You should use one of the several high-quality tutorials and/or textbooks available both online and in print to get started; SO will always be here for more specific questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-- Filter a list...
filter

-- ...of nested tuples where the first element of the second element of the tuple...
(\(_, (variable1, _)) ->

-- ...is not an element of [something1, something2]
variable1 `notElem` [something1, something2])
```

`(_, (varible1, _))` deconstructs a nested tuple, and names one of the elements. Look up deconstruction to understand what's going on there.

Comment: So does it return List of "nested" tupples ?

Comment: Yes. It would accept a list of something like `[(1, (2, 3)), (9, (8, 7))]`, and return a list of the same type (potentially with some elements removed). Honestly, the nested tuples here kind of make things messy. I might have `map`ped the list first to remove the nesting unless you actually needed nested tuples to use later.

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation :D

Comment: No problem. Always nice to have an excuse to look at Haskell code every once in awhile.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start at the beginning.

```
\p -> e
```

is a *lambda abstraction* (an anonymous function) where `p` is a pattern and `e` is an expression that may use variables that appear in `p`.

```
(_, (variable1, _))
```

is a pattern constructed from the constructor `(,)`, which constructs pairs. Here are some pairs:

```
(1, 2)
("Hello", "world!")
(1, (2, 3))
```

Here are some patterns which match pairs, used in lambda abstractions.

```
\(x, y) -> x
\(x,(y,z)) -> y
```

The second pattern matches a pair like `(1, (2, 3))` and gives the first element of the second element. In this case, it would give `2`. Its shape is like the pattern in your question, but what about the `_` in your pattern?

`_` is a valid variable name (variables can begin with underscores or lower-case letters). It is used to mean "a variable we don't use". The pattern `(_, (y, _))` is like the pattern `(x, (y, z))` except the only variable that has a name is `y`. Normally, you aren't allowed to reuse variable names in patterns. `(x,x)` is in invalid pattern, for instance. You are allowed to reuse `_` though because Haskell knows you intend to throw that value away.

Now we can understand the expression

```
\(_, (variable1, _)) -> variable1
```

It is a function of type `(a, (b, c)) -> b` which takes a pair whose second element is itself a pair and gives the first element of the second element.

Now we need to understand

```
variable1 `notElem` [something1, something2]
```

To understand this expression, we need to know what the backticks do. Surrounding an identifier in backticks turns it into an *infix* operator. Infix operators are usually spelled with symbols, like `x + y` and `xs ++ ys`. The backticks let us convert normal identifiers, like `notElem`, into infix operators. This means that the above expression is the same as

```
notElem variable1 [something1, something2]
```

`notElem` is a function which takes an item and a list of items of the same type and gives `True` if the item *does not* appear in the list and `False` otherwise. It is the opposite of the `elem` test for membership.

Finally, `filter`. `filter p xs` is a function that takes a *predicate* `p` (i.e., a function which returns a `Bool`) and uses it to filter the list `xs`. `filter` gives a new list where elements (call them `x`) are included if `p x` is true. This filters the list of `xs` and gives a new list whose elements are those for which the predicate is true. For example,

```
> filter even [1,2,3,4]
[2,4]
```

So, we have

```
filter                  -- filter a list
  (\(_, (variable1, _)) -- by matching on the first element
                        -- of the second element of a pair
                        -- and calling it 'variable1'
     -> variable1 `notElem` [something1, something2])
                        -- and giving `True` if the element
                        -- is neither 'something1' nor 'something2'
```

This gives a function which takes a list of pairs whose second element is a pair and filters it to a list of pairs whose second element is a pair whose first element is neither `something1` nor `something2`.

We can apply it, calling it `f` below:

```
f = filter (\(_, (varible1, _)) -> variable1 `notElem` [something1, something2])

> f [(1,(something1,2)), (1,(something3,3))]
[(1,(something3,3))]
```